# Aptana Studio 3 stand alone version will not reconize php 7.1.3 syntax in linux

Tags: php

Even after I added the php 7.1.3 executable to my version of AptanaStudio 3, it still will not reconize my script which uses a method with a return type declaration.  Aptana seems to only recognize loosely typed method definition syntax like what is used in php 5.6.

How can I get Aptana Studio to recognize my newer version of php (7.1.3)?

`public function get_name (string $name): string
       {
            $this->$name = $name;
            return $this->name;

       }`

The above code is an example of code that produces an error in my AptanaStudio 3 IDE.  However, when I run the code from my browser using my apache server, it runs like a charm.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?